# What's the bracket in user_path (user) for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wish to know what's the `(user)` for. I am having trouble understanding rails routing system.

Is `user_path(@user)` the same as `user_path(user)`?

Comment: Depends on the situation. You might want to read about [instance variables](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) in ruby.

Comment: It's a method call. If you're not sure what those are you need a better Ruby reference like the [Pragmatic Guide](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby).

Comment: I understand user_path(@user) => # user/1 but I don't quite get user_path(user). Is it a local variable?

Answer (score 0):

That is the arguments you give to the user_path method when you call it. Since the path generated is something like /user/25 the object user points to is used to get that ID number.

@user is an instance variable, usually set in the controller (Rails copies these into the View before rendering the Erb template), whereas user is either a local variable or a method call, perhaps given as explicit local variable in the render call or defined as a method in your ApplicationHelper module.